# First time using binary having trouble?

Tags: javascript, binary, bit-manipulation

Why does this return 10010 instead of 00001?

```
0110 >> 2 // 10010
```

I thought the bits would be shifted to the right 2 times, but they're not. The output I expected was `0001` or 1 but I got 0 instead. Why is this?

Comment: could you give more complete code - what is the type of the numbers you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0110 is an **octal** constant because it starts with a zero:

```
>>> 0110
72
>>> 0110 >> 2
18
>>> bin(_)
'0b10010'
```

This is Python, but the same is true of many other languages with octal constants (Java, C, JavaScript, ...). Not all languages provide binary constants. If you don't have them, you can use hexadecimal constants instead (0b0110 is 0x6, for example).

Comment: You take the binary number in groups of four (starting at the LSB), and convert each group to hex (0000 - 1001 are 0-9, then 1010 is A, 1011 is B, 1100 is C, 1101 is D, 1110 is E, 1111 is F). Octal requires memorizing fewer groups (since you do groups of three), but it tends to be less frequently used since 3 doesn't evenly divide powers of two.

Comment: Yep. So for a number like 1010001001011, you group it as 1 0100 0100 1011 and convert as `0x144B`.

Comment: Okay I get the letter conversions, but not the number conversions (0-9). So 0000 is 0 but how do I get to 1, 2, 3 and so on?

Comment: See FatalError's answer for a full list (a comment is not a good place for a table).

Answer (score 1):

Your number is not being interpreted as binary, but rather *octal* (base 8). Octal `0110` is `72` in decimal, or `1001000` in binary.  When you right shift by 2, that becomes `10010` as you are seeing.

It's common in programming languages that a leading zero means octal. Depending on the language you are using, there may or may not be a way to specify a binary literal.

A more universal way to express a binary number would be using hex since each nibble (hex digit) is exactly 4 bits.

```
0 0000
1 0001
2 0010
3 0011
4 0100
5 0101
6 0110
7 0111
8 1000
9 1001
A 1010
B 1011
C 1100
D 1101
E 1110
F 1111
```

So, to make 0110 (binary) we'd use 0x6. To make 01101101 we'd use 0x6D.

Comment: I'm using JavaScript so I don't think there is a way to do that. thx any way

Comment: I am surprised that the answer is being rendered in binary. Or is the answer `18`, and you are translating it for us to `10010`?

Comment: alert(0110 >> 2);  // 18    alert(110 >> 2); // 27

Comment: @Floris Yes I'm just translating it.